# How do I set intervals for values in DateTimeAxis

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

How to set interval with 5 or 10 minutes value for example.
When I am wrtiting

```
new OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis()
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
            IntervalType=DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes,
            IntervalLength=5
        };
```

It does not work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Interval=5` instead of `IntervalLength=5`